# awk ignore quoted delimiters `echo 'a "b1 b2" c'| awk '{print $2}'`

Tags: awk

The following will output `"b1` as it recognizes the quoted space as a field delimiter. How do I tell awk to ignore quoted delimiters so that this would output `b1 b2` or `"b1 b2"`

```sh
echo 'a "b1 b2" c'| awk '{print $2}'
```

I see the following two related posts, but I'm having trouble getting the solutions to work. I was hoping to find a simple solution. Field parsing is awk's specialty, right?

[awk ignore delimiter inside single quote within a parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372907/awk-ignore-delimiter-inside-single-quote-within-a-parenthesis)
[What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk)

Comment: `awk '{print $2}' FS=\"`

Comment: Are you actually trying to parse CSV files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk doesn't have the simple, convenient support for quoted fields that I wanted. I also looked at cut and that didn't either.

Another widely available bash shell tool called csvcut included as part of a bundle of tools called csvkit does provide easy support for quoted fields. My data is space delimited, not comma delimited, but I can easily specify a space delimiter to the csvcut tool.

This is what I wanted:

```sh
# Gives a
echo 'a "b1 b2" c d e' | csvcut -d ' ' -c 1
# Gives b1 b2
echo 'a "b1 b2" c d e' | csvcut -d ' ' -c 2
# Gives c
echo 'a "b1 b2" c d e' | csvcut -d ' ' -c 3
```

Answer (score 4):

With `gawk` (GNU awk) you can use the `FPAT` special variable to define how a field looks like instead of being limited to specify a delimiter:

```
echo 'a "b1 b2" c'| gawk '{print $2}' FPAT='("[^"]+")|[^[:blank:]]+'
```

Here we say: A field is either a `"` followed by non `"` chars and a closing `"` -> `("[^"]+")`
... or `|` a sequence of non-blank chars -> `[^[:blank:]]+`

These regexes will be evaluated in order, therefore a field enclosed in `""` has precedence over the second pattern, the sequence of non blank chars (awk's default).

---

See GNU awk manual: [Defining fields by content](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html)

Comment: Unfortunately a field containing a double quoot (like i.e. 'a "b1""b2" c' , where $2="b1""b2") will break this, but it's a nice feature of gawk, which I never used...

Comment: Yeah, it's nice. As long as the data follows at least _some_ standard, you can just change the pattern. If the data can be anything, it's impossible to parse it.

Comment: Please fix your FPAT to include the last field `g1` in the following command  `echo 'a "b1 b2" "c1 c2 c3" d "e1 e2" ftext e g1' |awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)print $i}' FPAT='("[^"]+")|[^[:blank:]]+'` as it is working great but the last field

Comment: It should be `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` in your example. Note: `<=` instead of `<`

Answer (score 0):

Shortest answer:

```
echo 'a "b1 b2" c'| awk -F\" '{print $2}'
```

will output:  b1 b2

Comment: Perfect! That works! I saw similar questions get blocked as duplicates, but the other SO answers I reviewed were far more complicated. This is really simple and exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: How would I adapt this to a comma scenario like `echo 'a,"b1,b2",c'| awk -F',' '{print $2}'`?

Comment: @clay This code assumes the middle column is always quoted and the first column is never quoted and there are no escaped quotes.

Comment: @melpomene, yikes. those are unacceptable assumptions. I'm giving a simplified example of real data that won't fit that.

Comment: @clay then you've over-simplified your example. There's dozens of ways to get the output you posted from the input you posted and almost all of them won't work for your real input. You need to provide more truly representative ample input/output if you want a robust but concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you look for this way:

```
awk '{split($0,a,/^"|" "| "|" |"$/);j=a[1]!=""?0:1;print a[2+j]}'
```

I think you can get a way where it fail ...